# JavaScript IF statement evaluating TRUE incorrectly - why?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, if-statement, logic

I have a very, very simple logical test of the number of licenses a customer has purchased vs. the number they have used:

```
else if(utype == "3"){
           var tech_lic = $("#technician_lic").val();
           console.log('tech lic = ' + tech_lic)
           var tech_allow = $("#technician_lic_allow").val();
           console.log('tech allow = ' + tech_allow)
           if(tech_lic >= tech_allow)
            {
              alert("You must purchase more licenses to create this Technician");
              return false;
            }
```

I threw in the console.log statements trying to debug this - normally they aren't there.

Console.log when I click "add" button:

```
tech lic = 4    application.js:262
tech allow = 100    application.js:264
```

Then we hit "You must purchase more licenses" alert in the window.

WHAT THE HECK?

How can 4 >= 100 evaluate true?

Comment: The `if` statement does a correct evaluation. It is a lexicographical comparison, and as such returns true for "4" being more than "100".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `.val` returns a string.  `'4'` is indeed greater than or equal to `'100'`.  Cast the values to numbers first (if you know that they are always numbers for the purposes of this comparison).

```
if (+tech_lic >= +tech_allow)
```

Comment: It is an implicit conversion. From a performance perspective implicit conversions take the same amount of time as using parseInt so it is a valid cast. Be careful of chaining like this though, if you are using implicit cast on multiple items in a row some parenthesis can go a long way.

Comment: @TravisJ what do you mean by "some parentheses can go a long way?"

Comment: @ExplosionPills - In order to make sure that there is no concatenation between values. For example, `+tech_lic >= +tech_allow + +tech_min` would get rather sloppy, and so some parentheses in there will make sure the proper value is derived. `+tech_lic >= (+tech_allow) + (+tech_min)`. This was not a note to you as much as to others who might want to use this on many values at once in a row.

Comment: @TravisJ—it's not "implicit conversion", the [unary + operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) converts the expression to a number, it's as explicit as using `Number(…)`. And there is no chance that `+x++y` will be interpreted as anything other than `+x + +y` (except perhaps by a human), ECMAScript syntax isn't **that** sloppy. ;-)

Comment: You got me - one of the values coming from the Rails Model was for sure an Integer - but the other was being returned from COUNT - anyway, I added "to_i" to force my values to Integers in my view, and left the JavaScript as-is - works.  I've given this the right answer because they were strings, though I solved the problem in a different way - this is a neat trick.

Answer (score 3):

You are evaluating them as strings, so "4" IS greater than "100".

You will need to cast them as integers before comparison:

```
var tech_lic = parseInt($("#technician_lic").val(), 10);
var tech_allow = parseInt($("#technician_lic_allow").val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

The string "4" is greater than "100", whereas the number 4 is less than 100.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that `4 >= 100` is true, it's that `"4" >= "100"` is true.

The values that you get are strings, so they will be compared lexically, not numerically.

Parse the values into numbers:

```
var tech_lic = parseInt($("#technician_lic").val(), 10);
var tech_allow = parseInt($("#technician_lic_allow").val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

```
if(Number(tech_lic) >= Number(tech_allow))
{
   // Do your stuff
}
```